# When UpdatePanel make PostBack to another one

Tags: asp.net, updatepanel

I have a complicated case, so I can't post it.

I have two `UpdatePanels` with two `UserControls` inside them, like the following:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <A:u1 ID="u1" runat="server" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel2" runat="server" UpdateMode="Conditional">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <A:u2 ID="u2" runat="server" />
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

In this sample, the `PostBack` in `u1` doesn't effect on `u2`. but in my code the `PostBack` in the first `UserControl` made a `PostBack` in the second.

What are the expected reasons ??

Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is by design: when a partial postback occurs, the whole page is rendered again even if only part of the resulting markup is sent to the client. Thus, both your user controls go through their lifecycles again, even if only `u1` is updated.

If you want to detect that case, you can use the [IsInAsyncPostBack](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.scriptmanager.isinasyncpostback.aspx) property:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page).IsInAsyncPostBack) {
        // This is a partial postback.
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but in the sample which I wrote, I added a break-point in `Page_Load` of the `UserControls` and it isn't called when the  other one make a `PostBack`

Comment: @John, interesting, it [definitely should be called](http://forums.asp.net/p/1023109/1389657.aspx). Is your breakpoint set right at the beginning of the handler?

Comment: Thanks, You're right. but in the two `UserControls` it's entered to the if stetement. sorry but why?

Comment: @John, it probably enters the `if` statement because you're in a partial postback, which is the intent. That code is meant to differentiate between partial postbacks (coming from an UpdatePanel) and full postbacks (resulting in the whole page being refreshed).